# Returning a JSON blob from jQuery.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, lexical-scope

I have a function where I'm making a call to a MVC controller that returns a JSON blob, with the contents of some back-end action.  This JSON blob is being used to populate a table that is presented to the end-user.

My function currently looks something like this:

```
function getJsonFromController(path) {
    var blob = null;

    $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        blob = data;
        console.log('inside getjson : ' + blob);
    });

    console.log('outside getjson : ' + blob);
    return blob;
}
```

...And a calling action that looks like this:

```
$('#action-button').click(new function () {
    blob = getJsonFromController('A/B?pageId=1');

    console.log('in click event: ' + blob);
    $.tmpl($template, blob).appendTo($('#table-body'));
});
```

When I run the webpage/action that calls this, I get the following results, in the given order:

```
outside getjson: null
in click event: null
inside getjson: [object Object]
```

I've attempted some other configurations (.complete of .getJSON(), directly returning a value from $.getJSON()) to attempt to echo the 'data' from the callback out to the enclosing scope's blob variable, but so far, the blob only appears to have value within the getJSON callback.

That being said, I'm also aware that JavaScript is a lexically scoped language, so it could be a matter of all the anonymous function chains being executed.

The question: I can see that my blob is appearing correctly inside $.getJSON.  Now, how do I get my blob out?

Comment: It's an **asynchronous mechanism**.  The callback to `$.getJSON()` happens way after the `$.getJSON()` itself returns.

Comment: ... and as to how you do it, well, you don't bring the blob to the code - you bring the code to the blob.  Handle it *inside* the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX requests are asynchronous. You may do it synchronous (note that it will freeze your web page until request is done), but suppose better will be to do something like below:

```
function getJsonFromController(path) {
    var blob = null;

    $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        blob = data;
        console.log('inside getjson : ' + blob);
        $.tmpl($template, blob).appendTo($('#table-body'));
    });
}
```

And click:

```
$('#action-button').click(new function () {
    blob = getJsonFromController('A/B?pageId=1');
});
```

Comment: There's no point returning "blob" from the "getJsonFromController()" function; it will always be `null`.

Comment: @Pointy - I know. Just not cleaned out copy/pasted code. Edited it

Comment: Accepted your answer, and it's working!  But one question remains: how would one do .getJSON synchronously?

Comment: see [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). You need code below "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:". You should use it, but with additional setting: `async:false` (See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). But I would not do that. I'm almost sure you do not need it and freezing of a web page is not what users want to see.